# AUTHBIND: Unable to authbind with tomcat 6 on redhat host

Tags: tomcat, authbind

I have a redhat linux server with tomcat 6.0.39 installed. Before I deploy any web application and open my server to the public I would like to learn how to run tomcat startup script with my tomcat user binding to the 80 port.

This is what I have done so far:

1. Changed port 8080 -> 80; 8443 -> 443 in my server.xml
2. The tomcat directory is owned by my tomcat user.
3. Installed authbind.
4. under /etc/authbind/byport I created two files 80, 443 and made them executable and changed the owner to tomcat.
5. Inside the startup.sh I changed (exec "$PGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@") to ("exec authbind --deep "$PGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@")

   After following those steps (which is pretty much what most articles tell you to do) I still get permission denied when starting up my tomcat, complaining that it cannot bind ports 80, 443.

   If you could provide any help I would greatly appreciate it,
   Thanks!

Comment: I know this isn't your question but one thing that I have success with is doing reverse proxy load balancing [through regular Apache httpd](https://dpaste.de/xyWU) It usually only involves like four lines of configuration and you can eventually get fancy with it and start load balancing between multiple Application Servers or hosting the application server on a different machine/platform than the rest of your site (if it's split up)

Comment: One other use for doing it the `ProxyPass` way is that I typically have an easier time managing my certs with regular `httpd` and doing it that way gets me out of having to do anything with `keytool`

Comment: I've used Joel's method as well and it works well for both Apache and Nginx.

Comment: I appreciate both your inputs/suggestions. The issue is that I was told to use authbind so I need to figure out what I have been doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

I found these slightly different steps which may help you out.

1. Install authbind
2. Make port 80 available to `authbind` (you need to be root):

   ```
   $ sudo touch /etc/authbind/byport/80
   $ sudo chmod 500 /etc/authbind/byport/80
   $ sudo chown glassfish /etc/authbind/byport/80
   ```
3. Make IPv4 the default (`authbind` does not currently support IPv6). To do so, create the file `TOMCAT/bin/setenv.sh` with the following content:

   ```
   CATALINA_OPTS="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"
   ```
4. Change `startup.sh`

   ```
   exec authbind --deep "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"
   # OLD: exec "$PRGDIR"/"$EXECUTABLE" start "$@"
   ```

#### References

- [Running Tomcat on port 80 in a user account](http://www.2ality.com/2010/07/running-tomcat-on-port-80-in-user.html)

Comment: That worked perfectly, that you very much for the solution.

Comment: @user3513075 - yup, please remember to upvote and vote this A as accepted if it resolved your issue to your satisfaction.